# nested For loop pattern in c++

Tags: c++, nested-for-loop

in c++, when I am making nested For loop and I am trying to calculate the factorial...I don't get the correct factorials...I don't know why. For example factorial of 5 is 120 but here it results in 34560. why?
and here is the code:

```
int fact=1;
    
for (int number=1; number<=10; number++) {
    for (int i=1; i<=number; i++)
       
           fact=fact*i;
           
           cout <<"factorial of "<<number<<"="<<fact<<"\n";
}
```

here is it pictured: [image: nested For loop]

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: You are using OnlineGDB.  A fundamental skill of programmers of all levels is [knowing how to step through your code in a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173) like GDB.  You would have found your mistake very quickly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to re-initialize `fact` for each number.

```
int fact=1;
    
for (int number=1; number<=10; number++) {
    fact = 1;
    for (int i=1; i<=number; i++)
       
           fact=fact*i;
           
           cout <<"factorial of "<<number<<"="<<fact<<"\n";
}
```